# VBA Excel work with strings

Tags: vba

I have following string values in cells like

```
"EnglishText / OtherLanguageText"
or
"UniversalText"
```

I need to get 2 substrings from that like 
"EnglishText" and "OtherLanguageText" 
or 
"UniversalText" (text which not contain "/")

Im selecting data with command

```
wbImportFrom.Sheets("Sheet 4").Cells(4, 6 + x).Value
```

How can i do that ? :-)
Thank you

Comment: in VBA use `Split()` and on the spreadsheet `=FIND()` and `=MID()`

Comment: Thank you, i used instr() instead of FIND()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Split function, and use the "/" as the delimiter.

Something like

```
My_String = Sheets("Sheet 4").cells(4, 6 + x).value
String_array = Split(My_String,"/")
```

should do the trick.  Bear in mind that you will then be working with an array.

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx